# Content editors get access denied when attaching new language version to a media item

Tags: media-library, multilingual

Our content editors get an error when they try to upload a new version of a document (or any other media item). Steps they take:

1. Go to media library
2. Upload a file (with advanced options) as versioned media
3. File gets uploaded - go to the newly created item
4. Switch language
5. Create a version of the item in this language
6. Click "attach" to upload the version of the asset in that language
7. Access error...

[image]

Image is taken with custom errors off..
In the logs we can see:

```
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException
Message: Application access denied.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.HasAccess(Boolean accessAllowed, String message)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Attach.AttachForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

If we try the same with an admin user, everything works fine.

Using Sitecore 9.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a security issue (bug) in Sitecore that can be easily fixed:

- Switch to the core database in the Desktop.
- Open Content Editor and navigate to the `/sitecore/content/Applications/Dialogs/Upload` item.
- Click the `Security` tab and grant the `sitecore\Author` role Read access right to this item

After that non-admin users with Author roles will be able to attach contents to the Media items.

Thx to Sitecore Support for the fix.

ps: I could not find the bug reference number (173612) in the release notes of 9.1 so it might still be present there.